# Double absolute value in inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm working on this problem:

$|3x-1|>|x^2-2x+3|$

I split it up into the four cases:

$3x-1>x^2-2x+3$

$3x-1>-x^2+2x-3$

$1-3x>x^2-2x+3$

$1-3x>-x^2+2x-3$

and solved for each of the cases. 
I got all real numbers, $1<x<4$ , $x<1, x>4$, and no solutions for values of x. However, this does not work. The answer is $1<x<4$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think that your method does not work ?

Comment: I graphed all the equations, including the original one, and the answers did not match up. The intervals were contadictory, expecially the ones involving $1$ and $4$ as bounds.

Answer (score 3):

Credit: Someone pointed out that $$x^2-2x+3=(x-1)^2+2>0$$ earlier though the post has been deleted. This observation simplifies the working.

Remark: $$|x^2-2x+3|=x^2-2x+3, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$ Two of your cases should not be considered.

If $x \geq \frac13$, then we  have to solve for
$$3x-1 >x^2-2x+3$$
$$0>x^2-5x+4$$
$$0>(x-4)(x-1)$$
$$1 < x<4$$

If $x<\frac{1}{3}$, then we have to solve for

$$1-3x > x^2-2x+3$$
$$0>x^2+x+2$$

which has no solution.

Hence conclusion, $$1 < x<4$$

Comment: I apologize about the cases. Let me add them. However the right answer to this question is $1<x<4$...

Comment: I think the mistake is when you consider $|x^2-2x+3|=-x^2+2x-3$, you have to figure out the value of $x$ when this happens. Unfortunately, this never happens.